# Vertically aligned extended monitor: One display in landscape mode while the other is in portrait mode

Tags: multiple-monitors, projector

I have a projector (NEC PE410HG), that I want to use in portrait mode, while having my main screen in landscape mode as normal. I can't figure out how to do it properly.

If I extend the screen, and select Portrait mode for the projector, it is as if I just tilt the projector. For instance, if I move my cursor up and down, it will go from right to left on the canvas.

This does not work:
[image]

Is what I want possible? The projector can not be turned on the side, and I'm using Windows 7.

**UPDATE**: I think it might be easier to have it in landscape mode, and just crop it so that it looks like 720x1200, instead of 1920x1080. However, I haven't found out how to do that either. It doesn't seem to be an easy way to do it..?

Comment: Well...did you tilt your projector?

Comment: @SBI: As I stated in the question, the projector cannot be tilted.

Comment: Unless your projector supports changing / rotating the projection area, there is no chance to just do this from windows.

Comment: Bugger! @SBI: Do you know if cropping the image is impossible too?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is dead simple, here is KB's response:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-extend-dual-monitors-vertically/16c24ac3-602e-4d4c-baf2-287453d7eb3e?db=5

Right-click on a blank place on the desktop;
Choose "Personalize."
Click "Display," 
Click "Change display settings." [You will see images of your two monitors there and identified as 1 and 2.] 
Drag one of them (whichever one you have on top) over the top of the other
Click "OK.

Thanks go to Ken

Comment: Unfortunately this is not it. I don't want the main screen in portrait mode, only the monitor. I don't care if I have to move the cursor between the displays horizontally or vertically. The problem I have is: If one is in landscape and the other is in portrait then it appears like I've just tilted the screen. If I move the cursor up to the other display (if aligned vertically as you suggest) then it will start moving left to right when it goes over to the other display.